# Python. Nested While Loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm a complete beginner trying to write a nested while loop using Python where I'd like a countdown to print three times.

Currently I have:

```
def amigo (counter, n):
    while counter > 0:
        while n > 0:
            print (n)
            n= n - 1
        print('Hola!')
        counter = counter - 1
```

Where I'm setting counter and n to both equal 2.

What I'd like it to do is print:

```
3
2
1
Hola!
3
2
1
Hola!
```

But right now it is printing:

```
3
2
1
Hola!
Hola!
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The problem is that you don't reset n at the end of the inner while loop, which causes it to still be 0 when the outer loop comes back. I'd suggest creating a copy of n to use as a loop index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### always reset counters.

Before each loop set counter value to initial position

For your inner loop it will be `i = n`

#### Use assignment with actions

Operator `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`

Then your code will be `n -= 1` instead of `n = n - 1`

#### Improved code

```
def amigo (counter, n):
    while counter > 0:
        i = n # Reset counter befor cycle. Used i to prevent editing n's value
        while i > 0:
            print (i)
            i -= 1 # Decrease i by 1, will loop from N to 1
        print('Hola!')
        counter -= 1 # Descrease counter by 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Where you have print (n), if I wanted it to count down, would I need to print (i)?

Comment: @Sam, yes! You are right, forgot to change it while fixed your code. Next time will use python before posting code